# Foreman exiting with code 1

Tags: heroku, foreman

I'm a complete heroku and nodejs newbie.  I just followed a tutorial to get a GroupMe bot running locally with heroku.  After running the command `foreman start`, I receive the following:

`18:10:00 web.1  | started with pid 24985
18:10:00 web.1  | exited with code 1
18:10:00 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes`

The procfile reads:

`web: node index.js`

How do I prevent exiting with code 1 above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might see that message if you don't have node installed on your local machine. You can check by typing

```
node --version
```

The Getting Started with Node.js on Heroku tutorial at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction might be helpful. It walks you through deploying a Node.js app step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the program manually:

```
node index.js
```

This will show you the actual errors you have.